# Django - Following ForeignKey relationships "backward" for entire QuerySet

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-queryset

is it possible to follow ForeignKey relationships backward for entire querySet?

i mean something like this:

```
x = table1.objects.select_related().filter(name='foo')
x.table2.all()
```

when table1 hase ForeignKey to table2.

in
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward
i can see that it works only with get() and not filter()

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You basically want to get `QuerySet` of different type from data you start with.

```
class Kid(models.Model):
    mom = models.ForeignKey('Mom')
    name = models.CharField…

class Mom(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField…
```

Let's say you want to get all moms having any son named `Johnny`.

```
Mom.objects.filter(kid__name='Johnny')
```

Let's say you want to get all kids of any `Lucy`.

```
Kid.objects.filter(mom__name='Lucy')
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use something like:

```
for y in x:
y.table2.all()
```

But you could also use `get()` for a list of the unique values (which will be `id`, unless you have a different specified), after finding them using a query.

So,

```
x = table1.objects.select_related().filter(name='foo')
for y in x:
   z=table1.objects.select_related().get(y.id)
   z.table2.all()
```

Should also work.

Comment: when i for loop it -  i'll hit the database alot and i want to avoid it.

Comment: in that case (where you have multiple items named `foo`) you should be able to use: `table1.objects.select_related().get(y.id).table2.all()` in the second `for` loop, which is the minimum amount of work you can do in this framework, as far as I can see.

Comment: The reason you'll have to do something like that, you're probably aware, is because for each `foo` there could be a different `table2`, or `ForeignKey`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [`values()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values) to fetch specific values of a foreign key reference. With `values` the select query on the DB will be reduced to fetch only those values and the appropriate joins will be done.

To re-use the example from Krzysztof Szularz:

```
jonny_moms = Kid.objects.filter(name='Jonny').values('mom__id', 'mom__name').distinct()
```

This will return a dictionary of Mom attributes by using the Kid QueryManager.